# SHA1 for Google apis

Tags: android, google-api, sha1, android-googleapiclient

Im a bit confused about how to obtain the SHA1 for my app.

I saw all the guides which suggest:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\user\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

But when i sign my app for distribution on Google play i sign it with a key (by applying key store path for a file which i created not related to the debug.keystore)

What does it mean? when i want to apply an SHA1 where should i take it from?

If i take it from what the guides say its like the SHA1 relies on the computer debug.keystore file, and what if i switch development to other computer?

Logic say its up to the Key store path which was created for the app signature

How should i obtain the proper SHA1?

Comment: SHA1 for distribution will always be your private `release.keystore` that you should generate. But your `debug.keystore` can be shared accross computers in `~/.android/debug.keystore` for example.

Comment: So what is debug.keystore for? testing purposes but when goin live its mandatory to change?

Comment: `debug.keystore` is just to sign your app (because your device needs a signature) but this signature is for development only and will never go live. When publishing an APK it needs to be signed with a release keystore (the APK uploader detects such errors anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new debug certificate, which is then used on several computers and use SHA1 of that one.

You would then use it like this in your gradle config, note use your own paths, this is for demo only

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
         .....
    }
    debug {
        storeFile file(String.format("%s/%s/%s", "$rootProject.projectDir", "keys", "debug.keystore"))
        storePassword "android"
        keyAlias "debug"
        keyPassword "android"
    }
}
```